# how to add the multiple row data into postgresql db using django

Tags: django

I want to create a table inside the Django forms and the table consists of number of rows with different data. Whenever I run the code in database it shows only the 1st row data and not the next row data pls solve me this...

Comment: Please add some code. what have you done ?

Answer (score 0):

```
views.py

def personalDetails(request):

    if request.method == "POST":
        print(request.POST.copy().dict())
        Emp_form = EmployeeForm(request.POST)
        id_form = IdForm(request.POST)
        lan_form = LangForm(request.POST)
        fam_mem = FamilyMembers(request.POST)

        if Emp_form.is_valid():
            print('is valid')
            emp1 = Emp_form.save()
            id_details = id_form.save(commit=False)
            id_details.applicant = emp1
            id_details.save()
            lan_details = lan_form.save(commit=False)
            lan_details.applicant = emp1
            lan_details.save()
            fam_details = fam_mem.save()
            fam_details.applicant = emp1
            fam_details.save()
        else:
            return render(request, 'Employee1_app/personal_details.html', {'form': Emp_form,
                                                                          'idform':id_form,
                                                                          'lanform':lan_form,
                                                                          'familymem':fam_mem,
                                                                          })
    Emp_form = EmployeeForm()
    id_form = IdForm()
    lan_form = LangForm()
    fam_mem = FamilyMembers()

    context = {'form': Emp_form,
               'idform': id_form,
               'lanform': lan_form,
               'familymem': fam_mem}
    return render(request, 'Employee1_app/personal_details.html',context)




personaldetails.html

   <table class="table table-bordered">
                <thead>
                    <tr>
                        <th>Name</th>
                        <th>Relation</th>
                        <th>Age</th>
                        <th>Dob</th>
                        <th>occupation</th>
                        <th>organisation</th>
                        <th>Actions</th>

                    </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody>
                     <tr>

                        <td>{{familymem.name}}</td>
                        <td>{{familymem.relation}}</td>
                        <td>{{familymem.age}}</td>
                        <td>{{familymem.dob}}</td>
                        <td>{{familymem.occupation}}</td>
                        <td>{{familymem.org_designation}}</td>
                        <td>
                            <a class="add" title="Add" toggle="tooltclass="materialicons"></i></a>
                            <a class="edit" title="Edit" data-toggle="tooltip"><i class="material-icons"></i></a>
                            <a class="delete" title="Delete" data-toggle="tooltip"><i class="material-icons"></i></a>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
```

Comment: In personaldetails.html i created a table and a row if the user need to create a next row the data entered in the next row is not getting into database postgresql how can i solve this

Comment: I need multiple rows which needed to entered in the database too